# Custom user fallback button in LAContext Not Support in ios8.3

Tags: ios, touch-id, ios8.3

I have customized the fallback button by setting `localizedFallbackTitle` to "Use Password". It worked. But after I updated my iPhone to iOS 8.3, the fallback button disappeared on the TouchID view.

Is this the API updated or a bug of iOS 8.3?

How to fix it?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It works. It only shows up, when user fails for authentication via TouchId for first time. It come up in second step.

iOS 8.2, it was like :

[image]

Now, in iOS 8.3, it is in two steps :
First,

[image]

And second, if you fails in verifying your fingerprint.

[image]

`localizedFallbackTitle`(== "Enter Password" in above images) can be seen on second popup.

Comment: @Andrew  Yeah in some sense it is not good, but its very useful in case where being a developer you don't want user to enter your app via password. You can restrict user to use only 'TouchId'. Because password can be leaked somehow but your finger can't ;)

Comment: please submit a Radar bug. Thanks!

Comment: Same problem here. We actually preferred the fallback button the be shown all the time. radar://20937424

Comment: Of course Apple does not mention this in the docs; I was frantically trying to figure out why the “Enter Passcode” button was not showing up! Thanks @RoNiT.